# How to fix tomcat server not run my dynamic web project?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am using tomcat server , I build my dynamic web project and add to it external js files and other files ... it run fine ... But Now the tomcat run the specific code which I use js files and other files not correct .. I did not knew what the problem the tomcat was run fine why Now it did not run fine my dynmic web project ...  any body can help ?

Answer (score 0):

**Export your eclipse project as  war file and place in the tomcat/webapps folder.
Start your tomacat service** here http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftwcrewar.html